# finding surface area of hexgonal prism in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, x87, sasm

I am trying to find the surface area using this equation. A = 6*a*h+3*sqrt(3)*a^2
I do not fully understand how co-processor instructions actually work.

Here is currently by subprogram

```
enter       8,0
mov         [ebp-4],dword 2 ; Coprocessor instructions only work with
                            ; memory addresses. So we will store the number
                            ; 2 in a local variable on the stack (which
                            ; is the address ebp-4).

mov         [ebp-8],dword 6 ; ebp-8 = 6

;A = 6*a*h+3*sqrt(3)*a^2 where a is the base edge and h is height
fld         qword[ebp+8]    ; ST0 = a
fld         qword[ebp+16]   ; ST1 = a; ST0 = h
fmulp       st1     ; ST0 = h*a
mov         [ebp-8],dword 6 
fild        dword[ebp-8]        ; ST1 = h*a; ST0 = 6
fmulp       st1,st0     ; ST0 = h*a*6

fld         dword[ebp+8]    ; ST0 = a
fmul            st0                 ; ST0 = a^2
fild            dword[ebp-8]    ; ST1 = (a^2); ST0 = 3
fld         st0                 ; ST2 = (a^2); ST1 = 3; ST0 = 3   
fsqrt                               ; ST2 = (a^2); ST1 = 3; ST0 = sqrt(3)
fmulp       st1                 ; ST1 = (a^2); ST0 = 3*sqrt(3)
fmulp       st1                 ; ST0 = ((a^2)*3*sqrt(3)
```

I am looking for a better understanding on how I want to go about this and can you tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has a link to a good x87 tutorial: http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/index.html.  You should simplify this and do `3*sqrt(3)` by hand, putting the result in a constant.  No need to do extra sqrt and multiply at runtime; think like a compiler.

Comment: What is the question/problem ?